# How do I register an existing file (db) with sqlite3?

Tags: database, django, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database created using django. But I'm not sure how I can register that database with sqlite3? For example, when I get into sqlite3's shell and type .databases, I don't see the database I craeted. There's only 'main' listed.

Is there a way to register my existing database so it'll show up under sqlite's list of databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't have a "list of databases". It's not a client-server system, but operates only on a single file at a time - which you can specify when you start:

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.db
```

Django includes a command to start up the relevant database shell with the correct parameters:

```
manage.py dbshell
```